# CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-location

I am using core location in my application to get the location of the user when the application starts first and then on the entry of background to foreground. After taking the location

```
NSString *mylatitude = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude] description];
```

I am stopping the service as:

```
[locationController.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

[locationController.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

I am using a delegate class for getting the location whose object is locationController. Then again when coming back from background i am again starting the service by

```
[locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

everything works fine in simulator as well as on device.But in device log i saw one strange message like

```
CoreLocation: CLClient is deprecated. Will be obsolete soon.
```

I am totally confused where it is coming and why? Can anybody guide me on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It is not an issue. I also found this message in log and confused.
It is CoreLocation related message nothing damaged to your application. And also we can't prevent this message to generate. As per what I explored may be Whenever GPS chip is busy to get location, system will generate this message.